# How is the chart created if we only know that we divide into equal intervals?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am reading a text that presents the following chart.
[image]

It says that the chart shows the distribution of monthly returns (percentages) for an investment over $70$ years and it was constructed by dividing the range of returns into equal intervals $\approx$ $1$ and $(1/4)\%$.
But I am not clear how the numbers in the $X$-axis are determined (i.e.: $..-7,-3,1,6..$etc)
Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "X-axis" is the monthly returns in percentage for an investment over some unspecified number of years. For example, the most common monthly return in percentage (the mode) is $2.25\%$.

The $1.25\%$ is addressing the interval which each bar represents. Also, it is roughly $1.25\%$ and not exactly because not all the intervals are the same. The interval (-3,1) is separated $4\%$ by 4 bars while the interval (1,6) is separated $5\%$ by 4 bars. So, each bar should represent an interval of approximately $1.25\%$.

Note: The distribution looks roughly symmetric with some obvious and other possible outliers. The median is around $1\sim2.25\%$.

Comment: The number of years is 70. But it says 1(1/4) i.e. 1.25.

Comment: What do you mean by the 2.25% ?

Comment: You mean each bar has width 1.25?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?